# Making chi-square distribution out of unknown CDF

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, chi-squared

Suppose that the random variables X1,..., Xn are independent, and each random variable Xi has a continuous c.d.f. Fi. Also, let the random variable Y be deﬁned by the relation

Y = −2∑(i=1~n) log Fi(Xi). Show that Y has the χ2 distribution with 2n degrees of freedom.

I don't see where this is heading. Is it possible to derive the χ2 distribution out of absolutely unknown CDFs?

Comment: Definitely asked before here. Use the fact that $F(X_i)$ has a uniform distribution over $(0,1)$ for each $i$, independently of each other.

Comment: How can that prove it?? Shouldn't Y have to be ∑(i=1~2n)Z^2, where Z is standard normal distribution?

Comment: Couple of easy to verify facts: $-\ln X$ is exponential with mean $1$ whenever $X\sim U(0,1)$. A chi-square variable with df $2$ is also an exponential variable with mean $2$. And then using the 'additive property' of chi-square distribution would complete the proof.